# akamai dns management api

Tags: python, dns, akamai

Purpose: I am trying write a script to change CNAME records for a zone defined in Akamai Luna Control Center.

Question: I went through a nice detailed document that explains how to access Akamai API: https://developer.akamai.com/api/luna/config-dns/overview.html

All well and good; but what is missing [or atleast unclear to me] is the base url to access Akamai Luna Control Center API.

I have tried the below with no luck:

```
http://control.akamai.com/config-dns/v1/zones/{zone}
```

I keep getting a Page Not Found when I try to use the above URL.

Any one who knows what I am doing wrong? Any pointers on what the correct base url should be?

Comment: It looks like the base URL is customer-dependent. Look at the examples in the **Reference** section of the documentation.

Comment: They use the URL `http://mock-anon-711a234d3-akamaiopen2lunaconfigdnsproduction.apiary.io/config-dns/v1/zones/`

Comment: Barmar - thanks for your comment. Have opened a case with Akamai to get the base url....

Comment: I could get this working. Yes the base url is customer dependent. This was not so obvious to me to begin with. In any case; anyone reading this and is in a similar situation; here is the reference doc: https://developer.akamai.com/introduction/Luna_Setup.html

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the base URL and other credential pieces, you need to go through the Luna Provisioning process.

I strongly recommend you go through the Getting Started guide for the {OPEN} APIs, which will answer most of your questions.  As well, there is a signing library and sample code in python (api-kickstart) to get going.

```
https://developer.akamai.com/introduction/
```